# Yet another Subversion "Commit failed" MERGE of 'blabla': 200 OK

Tags: python, svn, tortoisesvn, post-commit, visualsvn-server

I get the infamous "MERGE of 'whatever': 200 OK" whenever I try to commit using a post-commit hook on Windows (running the repository and Trac locally), and I'm going crazy. I've been looking all over for a day now, without finding any solutions.

So here's how it's set up and what I've tried so far:

Settings:
Windows 7 (64-bit)
VisualSVN Server
TortoiseSVN
Trac 0.11.6

- I'm using the three standard scripts for post-commit on Windows.
- Everything works when I run post-commit.cmd from the command prompt with repo and changesetnumber as parameters.
- After extensive trouble-shooting, I found that if I remove the last line in trac-post-commit.cmd, **Python "%~dp0\trac-post-commit-hook.py" -p "%TRAC_ENV%" -r "%REV%" -u "%AUTHOR%" -m "%LOG%"**, the Commit failed error goes away.
- Adding **1/0** (generating a division by zero error) in the python script doesn't show anything different. From the command prompt I get an error, though.
- Removing all code in the python script also makes the commit failed go away, so I guess the culprit is in trac-post-commit-hook.py.

Perhaps if I could send the actual error to a log file, I could dig a little deeper, but I'm not sure how.

post-commit.cmd:

```
call %~dp0\trac-post-commit-hook.cmd %1 %2
```

trac-post-commit-hook.cmd:
http://trac.edgewall.org/browser/trunk/contrib/trac-post-commit-hook?rev=920

Thank you so much, it would mean alot if someone could assist a little here!
/Martin

Comment: Seems that the last pre block didn't work, so here's a link to the original trac-post-commit-hook I'm using: http://trac.edgewall.org/browser/trunk/contrib/trac-post-commit-hook?rev=920

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the error message while doing the SVN commit, you should be able to change:

```
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    if len(sys.argv) < 5: 
        print "For usage: %s --help" % (sys.argv[0]) 
    else: 
        CommitHook()
```

to:

```
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    if len(sys.argv) < 5: 
        print "For usage: %s --help" % (sys.argv[0]) 
    else: 
        try:
            CommitHook()
        except Exception, e:
            print >> sys.stderr, str(e)
            sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: Sorry, I tried to output the error to a file (couldn't see them in TortoiseSVN), but it didn't work.
I ran the below script in IDLE without problems, but when I tried to implement it in trac-post-commit-hook, nothing happens.

import sys
error_log = open("C:\error_log.txt", 'w')
sys.stderr = error_log
try:
    CommitHook()
except Exception, e:
    print >> sys.stderr, str(e)
f.close()
error_log.close()

Any tips? Thanks!